# How to disable the control panel ouput/view in a module, output nothing

Tags: module

I have written a module for expression engine with an admin control panel. I would like to be able to output some content to the screen without showing the control panel output. So just a blank screen. The purpose is I am trying to use the buffer, ob_start() etc, to put put content live on the screen as its being processed.

But by default the EE CP is called, and its called AFTER my script is run, so I think this is preventing the buffer from working. All I see is the final output and not the output as its being processed. It waits for my script to finish and then shows the content in the control panel view.

Is there a way to disable using the control panel view at all, and just output a blank screen? For example:

```
function export()
{
    echo 'I only want to see this and not the EE control panel!';
    echo 'But I see the control panel view below my content';

}
```

I cannot use exit() because this too waits for the script to finish before outputting the final contents. 
Thanks

Comment: Have you considered just dropping an iframe into your modules CP page and load a flat script inside of that?

Comment: I hadn't thought of it, no, but I would like access to EE methods, access to logged in user details etc. So the iFrame src script will still need to run through the module and have the same issue.